# Unable to select dropdown , Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by id

Tags: selenium

[image]

Unable to select a value in dropdown , element not interactable pops out when you do not put implicit wait and if you put it this error message pops out

> Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by

tried an approach like a textbox , where you select , click then enter a text , tried select statement

```
    Select fruits = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"drop-down-list-department\"]")));
    fruits.selectByValue("2");
    fruits.selectByIndex(2);

}
```

HTML

```
 <div class="content-splitter advance-contents">
    <table id="advance-table">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="text-align: left" valign="center">
                <input type="checkbox" id="check-status">
                <label for="check-status">Active 可交易</label>
                &nbsp;
                &nbsp;
                <input type="checkbox" id="check-vat">
                <label for="check-vat">12% VAT 税</label>
                &nbsp;
                &nbsp;
                <input type="checkbox" id="check-senior-5">
                <label for="check-senior-5">Senior / PWD 5% 年长优惠/残疾人5%</label>
                &nbsp;
                &nbsp;
                <input type="checkbox" id="check-senior-20">
                <label for="check-senior-20">Senior / PWD 20% 年长优惠/残疾人20%</label>
                &nbsp;
                &nbsp;
                <input type="checkbox" id="check-in-stock">
                <label for="check-in-stock">Discontinue In-Stock 货商断货</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height: 10px"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="advance-input-label">Chinese Name 中文名称:</td>
            <td class="advance-input-table">
                <input type="text" id="text-chinese-name" class="text-input-advance" maxlength="200">
            </td>
            <td rowspan="10">
                <div id="upload-div">
                    <form id="upload-file-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
                        <input type="hidden" name="wid" value="100000000003088">
                        <input type="file" name="photoImage" id="input-upload-file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif">
                    </form>
                    <input type="button" class="bttn-imp-create upload-button" value="+ Upload your image 上传照片" onclick="openfileUpload()">
                    <table id="upload-image-thumbnail-holder">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td>
                                <img id="upload-image-thumbnail" src="images/no_image.png">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </div>
                <div id="upload-div-buttons">
                    <table>
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td align="left">
                                <input type="button" class="bttn-imp-create select-another-image-button" value="Upload your image 上传照片" onclick="openfileUpload()">
                            </td>
                            <td align="right">
                                <input type="button" class="bttn-negative remove-image-button" value="Remove 删除">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="advance-input-label"> Client Barcode 包装条码:</td>
            <td class="advance-input-table">
                <input type="text" id="text-client-barcode-1" class="text-input-half" maxlength="20">
                <input type="text" id="text-client-barcode-2" class="text-input-half" maxlength="20">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="advance-input-label"> Supplier SKU 代码:</td>
            <td class="advance-input-table">
                <input type="text" id="text-supplier-sku" class="text-input-advance" maxlength="20">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="advance-input-label">Description 说明:</td>
            <td class="advance-input-table">
                <textarea class="text-input-advance" id="text-description" maxlength="1000"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="advance-input-label">Department 品种:</td>
            <td class="advance-input-table">
                <select id="drop-down-list-department" class="search-input-bar chzn-done" style="display: none;">
                     <option value="1">none</option><option value="2">Novelty</option><option value="100000000000024">代购</option><option value="100000000000017">休闲食品</option><option value="100000000000020">冻品</option><option value="100000000000019">厨房用品</option><option value="100000000000004">啤酒</option><option value="100000000000013">桶装面</option><option value="100000000000022">水果</option><option value="100000000000002">洋酒</option><option value="100000000000015">洗发水+沐浴乳</option><option value="100000000000009">火腿肠</option><option value="100000000000001">烟</option><option value="100000000000006">牛奶</option><option value="100000000000021">生活用品</option><option value="100000000000005">白酒</option><option value="100000000000007">糖果</option><option value="100000000000003">红酒</option><option value="100000000000014">自煮火锅</option><option value="100000000000023">药品</option><option value="100000000000012">袋装面</option><option value="100000000000018">面包</option><option value="100000000000016">饮料</option><option value="100000000000008">饼干</option><option value="100000000000011">鸡鸭爪+鸭翅+腿</option>                    </select><div id="drop_down_list_department_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single" style="width: 307.979166px;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single" tabindex="-1"><span>none</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chzn-drop" style="left: -9000px; width: 306px; top: 0px;"><div class="chzn-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" style="width: 271.021px;"></div><ul class="chzn-results"><li id="drop_down_list_department_chzn_o_0" class="active-result result-selected" style="">none</li><li id="drop_down_list_department_chzn_o_1" class="active-result" style="">Novelty</li><li id="drop_down_list_department_chzn_o_2" class="active-result" style="">代购</li><li id="drop_down_list_department_chzn_o_3" class="active-result" style="">休闲食品</li><li id="drop_down_list_department_chzn_o_4" class="active-result" style="">冻品</li><li id="drop_down_list_department_chzn_o_5" class="active-result" style="">厨房用品</li><li id="drop_down_list_department_chzn_o_6" class="active-result" style="">啤酒</li><li id="drop_down_list_department_chzn_o_7" class="active-result" style="">桶装面</li><li id="drop_down_list_department_chzn_o_8" class="active-result" style="">水果</li><li id="drop_down_list_department_chzn_o_9" class="active-result" style="">洋酒</li><li id="drop_down_list_department_chzn_o_10" class="active-result" style="">洗发水+沐浴乳</li><li id="drop_down_list_department_chzn_o_11" class="active-result" style="">火腿肠</li><li id="drop_down_list_department_chzn_o_12" class="active-result" style="">烟</li><li id="drop_down_list_department_chzn_o_13" class="active-result" style="">牛奶</li><li id="drop_down_list_department_chzn_o_14" class="active-result" style="">生活用品</li><li id="drop_down_list_department_chzn_o_15" class="active-result" style="">白酒</li><li id="drop_down_list_department_chzn_o_16" class="active-result" style="">糖果</li><li id="drop_down_list_department_chzn_o_17" class="active-result" style="">红酒</li><li id="drop_down_list_department_chzn_o_18" class="active-result" style="">自煮火锅</li><li id="drop_down_list_department_chzn_o_19" class="active-result" style="">药品</li><li id="drop_down_list_department_chzn_o_20" class="active-result" style="">袋装面</li><li id="drop_down_list_department_chzn_o_21" class="active-result" style="">面包</li><li id="drop_down_list_department_chzn_o_22" class="active-result" style="">饮料</li><li id="drop_down_list_department_chzn_o_23" class="active-result" style="">饼干</li><li id="drop_down_list_department_chzn_o_24" class="active-result" style="">鸡鸭爪+鸭翅+腿</li></ul></div></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="advance-input-label">Category 种类:</td>
            <td class="advance-input-table">
                <select id="drop-down-list-category" class="search-input-bar chzn-done" style="display: none;"><option value="1" selected="selected">none</option></select><div id="drop_down_list_category_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single" style="width: 307.979166px;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single" tabindex="-1"><span>none</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chzn-drop" style="left: -9000px; width: 306px; top: 0px;"><div class="chzn-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" style="width: 271.021px;"></div><ul class="chzn-results"><li id="drop_down_list_category_chzn_o_0" class="active-result result-selected" style="">none</li></ul></div></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="advance-input-label">Brand 品牌:</td>
            <td class="advance-input-table">
                <select id="drop-down-list-branch-id" class="search-input-bar chzn-done" style="display: none;">
                     <option value="1">none</option>                    </select><div id="drop_down_list_branch_id_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single" style="width: 307.979166px;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single" tabindex="-1"><span>none</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chzn-drop" style="left: -9000px; width: 306px; top: 0px;"><div class="chzn-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" style="width: 271.021px;"></div><ul class="chzn-results"><li id="drop_down_list_branch_id_chzn_o_0" class="active-result result-selected" style="">none</li></ul></div></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="advance-input-label"> Big Qty 大单位:</td>
            <td class="advance-input-table">
                <input type="text" id="text-big-quantity" placeholder="Numbers only" class="text-input" maxlength="20">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                 <input type="checkbox" id="check-sold-in-package">
                <span>Product Sold in Package 产品以包装出售</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</div>
```

I expect should be able to choose a dropdown value

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@class='advance-input-table' and ./preceding-sibling::*[contains(text(),'Department')]]")));
WebElement department = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='advance-input-table' and ./preceding-sibling::*[contains(text(),'Department')]]"));
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(department).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(1000);
act.moveToElement(department).click().build().perform();
Thread.sleep(1000);
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("drop-down-list-department"));
//update here
dropdown.submit();
Select fruits = new Select(dropdown);
act.moveToElement(dropdown).click().build().perform();
Thread.sleep(1000);
fruits.selectByValue("2");
```

And you can use also this method :

```
fruits.selectByVisibleText("Novelty");
```

Comment: when adding a webdriver if it exist is produces an error Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath

Comment: please share your html code(or web link if possible) and full error log.

Comment: i've updated the code please try, and info again, your `select` have this : `style="display: none;"`. Do you have to do a previous action to bring appear this `select` ?

Comment: tried it multiple times , sometimes produces : element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated but sometimes value = 2 cannot be manipulated or seen , when added explicit wait , still does not work . ( yes it has style="display: none;"

Comment: the element appear by manually ? my opinion this is element will appear after to do something. Because my understanding `style="display: none;"` not appear in page.

Comment: after clicking the show advance information , the dropdown shows , its a dropdown where in you can type text

Comment: i mean if opening by manually (without automation script) , when you landing on this pages, sure this is dropdown have appear without anything action?

Comment: after landing the page , the drop down does not exit . It shows when you click the advance information button

Comment: So please you must click `advance information button`, add some sleep, then interact with the dropdown.

Comment: it already does that , it clicks the button and waits for the dropdown but still error persists . All this time it clicks the button and waits for it

Comment: html code that you share is very limited information, please give more, many possibilities, maybe it inside `iframe` or etc.

Comment: it now clicks the dropdown and tries to select I think. but produces an error element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated. Tried changing on what to select by index , value and text but still does not work. When i changed the selectByIndex to 0 . it does not fail but other value fails

Comment: please try click index 0 and continue index 1, what happens ?

Comment: it clicks the dropdown and does not choose anything . same with the first code you have edited

Comment: By manually(human behaviour, not with coding), is the value list option appear ?

Comment: after clicking the dropdown it acts like a textbox/dropdown , where you can type and select

Comment: i've updated the answer again, please try again. I'm add :`dropdown.submit();` before click.

Comment: javascript error: Unable to find owning document , it clicks the dropdown then it errors

Answer (score 0):

> Java

```
WebElement categorie=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gh-cat-box\"]"));
        categorie.click();
        Select dropdown=new Select(categorie);
        dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Art");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While your code may provide the answer to the question, please add context around it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.

Comment: element not interactable but when you add an explicit wait , it produces Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located